# Modify ClusterRole for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rbac, k8s-serviceaccount, k8s-rolebinding

I want to use the ClusterRole **edit** for some users of my Kubernetes cluster (https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#user-facing-roles).

However, it is unfortunate that the user can be accessing and modifying Resource Quotas and Limit Ranges.

My question is now: How can I grant Users via a RoleBinding access to a namespace, such that the Role is essentially the CluserRole **edit**, but without having any access to Resource Quotas and Limit Ranges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `edit` role gives only *read* access to `resourcequotas` and `limitranges`:

```
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - bindings
  - events
  - limitranges
  - namespaces/status
  - pods/log
  - pods/status
  - replicationcontrollers/status
  - resourcequotas
  - resourcequotas/status
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

If you want a role that doesn't include read access to these resources, just make a copy of the `edit` role with those resources excluded.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Could you tell me where I could get the rights etc. (In yaml format or whatever) for each ClusterRole?

Comment: `kubectl get clusterrole edit -o yaml`